# Where can I find stories about the yakuza?

Tags: shadowrun-sr5, new-gm, story

I'm planning my first (short) adventure, replacing my group's previous GM for a few sessions. Thing is, I'm new to *Shadowrun*, and I don't have much background knowledge of the universe in general or Seattle in particular. I'm trying to have the plot involve the yakuza, and I'd like to read some stories to inspire my homebrew scenarios.

Where can I find more *Shadowrun* short stories like those in the rulebook? Is there a forum that hosts some?

Comment: I think this should be migrated, but sure to which community. Probably Science fiction and fantasy if you want more shadow run style stories.

Comment: @Escoce It's for sure a line-straddler, but I think folks more familiar with *Shadowrun* will be better able to help the querent locate *Shadowrun* short stories than those more familiar with short stories will be able to help the querent locate short stories set in *Shadowrun*.

Comment: Unfortunately, all shopping questions are off-topic on this site - and questions asking for lists doubly so.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's quite a bit of Yakuza-related material in older sourcebooks.

### Sourcebooks

- **Seattle Sourcebook** (FASA 7201) is an SR1 book, and doesn't have much beyond basic description. It's probably not worth tracking down.
- **Underworld Sourcebook** (FASA 7123) is an SR2 book, but considering that criminal cartels are the core of the book, it's got some good data and could be worth getting your hands on.
- **New Seattle** (FANPRO 10657) is SR3's equivalent to the Seattle Sourcebook. It's section on the Yakuza is longer, and more up-to-date with the timeline.
- **Mob War** (FASA 7326) covers the death of a Mafia don, and how the other syndicates (including the Yakuza) react.

As these are primarily source material rather than system material, the edition isn't really relevant. It's all a bit dated, timeline-wise, but is solid from a historical and thematic viewpoint.

## Adventures

- **Dark Angel** (FASA 7313) features the Yakuza as the primary antagonist.
- **Elven Fire** (FASA 7310) involves gang warfare, including the Yakuza.

These are both old modules, so the mechanics are useless for SR5. The basic plots could be used, and the characterization and descriptions could be useful.

## Novels

- **Crossroads** (FASA 5742) is the only one I recall that specifically involves the Yakuza.

There weren't many written under the FanPro/WizKids label, but I'm reasonably certain none of them involved the Yakuza.

I can't speak to any of the ones written under the Catalyst label; I haven't read them.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are researching all of the Shadowrun material listed above to ensure proper game-world flavor and consistency within your own homebrew modules/adventures; and assuming you want new, original material that will capture the attention of your players and spark their imagination; I recommend you start your writing research with Wikipedia. Get an overview of the Yakuza in the context of the real-world. To deepen your understanding, dig further into the Wikipedia article bibliography. If you enjoy this deeper research, acquire used books on Amazon, audiobooks on Audible, or movies (as stated above).

You may find an obscure story to adapt into an adventure ploy, or inspiration for story elements that will lead you to a new concoction. I enjoy this type of research when creating new stories for campaigns in the various systems/genres that I DM.